# replacing images inside MEDIA_ROOT doesn't change the images in live server

Tags: django, django-templates

i have avatar.png inside my /media/ folder and after a created some profiles i went and replaced the avatar.png with another with same name and it seems it doesn't change it at all, how to replace it all over django server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your Browser is still caching the file. Try to disable the cache in the developer mode or load the page with ctrl + r